# CSS animation on hamburger toggle menu not working properly

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to animate the dropdown menu that appears when user clicks on the hamburger toggle. I want the menu to "fadein" instead of just popping up.

The menu CSS:

```
.nav-menu {
  display: none; /* Hide the menu on small screens initially */
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3em 0;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.8s ease; /* Smooth fadein effect */
}
```

Toggler CSS:

```
.nav-toggle:checked ~ .nav-menu {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1; /* Fade in the menu */
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle" />
          <div class="nav-hamburger">
            <label for="nav-toggle" class="nav-icon" id="nav-icon">
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="nav-menu" id="nav-menu">
            <ul class="nav-list">
              <li class="nav-list-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li class="nav-list-item"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
              <li class="nav-list-item"><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
              <li class="nav-list-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

One way that the fade effect does work is if i set the .nav-menu display : block. In this way the menu is open but due to opacity being 0 its not visible, then if i click on the toggle, the menu fades in & out. I don't understand why it isn't working with display none.

I'm new to web development and this is my very first website, made using HTML & CSS, just to polish everything i have learnt so far.

I tried working with the display:block and making the item's unclickable but thats just putting things under the carpet. Inspected the code in chrome but couldn't figure out why it was happening.

Answer (score 1):

The `display` property cannot currently be animated. It’s clearly something we need, and [work is occurring](https://css-tricks.com/so-youd-like-to-animate-the-display-property/) to make it possible, but that’s for the future.

So for now, to do this requires some Javascript. Start off with the submenu styled as:

- `display: none`
- `opacity: 0`
- `transition: 300ms`

When a user opens the menu, do this:

- `display: block`
- `opacity: 1` (this change will transition over 300ms)

And when a user closes the menu, do this:

- `opacity: 0` (this change will transition over 300ms)
- wait for the transition to complete, then set `display: none`

Use the [setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) method to wait for the transition to complete before initiating the change.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Guess ill have to start with javascript before i can move any further.

Comment: Yes, Javascript is an essential part the web, so that will be time well spent.